# How can I silence Xcode anaylzer reporting "potential leak of an object stored into 'self'" for class method

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am almost certain that I don't have a leak in this code, yet the Xcode analyzer reports that there is a "potential" leak (Xcode 4.6.1).

```
+ (MySHA1hash *)sha1HashWithHashBytes:(unsigned char *)hash length:(unsigned int)length;
{
   return [[[MySHA1hash alloc] initWithHashBytes:hash length:length] autorelease];
}
```

[image: XCode analyzer error screenshot]

If the problem is that Xcode is reporting a false positive, I would like to figure out how to structure the code in a way to silence the warning.

It is also the possible that I am leaking in a way I don't understand, but If someone can see how I am actually leaking I would be glad to get that feedback as well.

This must have something to do with the init functions I call, because if I simply replace initWithHashBytes with init, then the leak is no longer reported.  To that end I also include the body of initWithHashBytes.

```
- (id)initWithHashBytes:(unsigned char *)hash length:(unsigned int)length
{
    if (hash != nil && length <= SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:length];
        self = [self initWithHash:data];
    }
    else {
        self = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithHash:(NSData *)hash
{
    if ([hash length] <= SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH && (self = [super init]) != nil) {
        finished = YES;
        [hash getBytes:sha_Result];
        hashValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[hash hash]];
    }
    else {
        self = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This is not a false positive. Hint: the word "potential" is included in the report.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was getting down votes because of the previous title of the question.  I have changed that.  I still think the question is very reasonable.  How do you silence an error / warning that you don't believe to be an correct.

Comment: I've generally found that the best way to "silence" analyzer complaints is to fix the problems.

Comment: Well, That is probably true.  I guess I am under the assumption that no analyzer is perfect.  There is probably a reason that it is complaining, and there is a good chance it is right (as in this case it was), but I also assume it is possible that a static analyzer can be incorrect.

Comment: There are cases (such a misnaming a method as "new...") that can confuse the analyzer and cause it to report a leak that isn't present, but they've always been "real" errors, in my experience, just not always "real" leaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
self = nil;
```

in `initWithHashBytes:` (and `initWithHash:`) is the issue. You are allocating an object, but if you return `nil` from from `initWithHashBytes:`, that object will be leaked, because you'll call `autorelease` on `nil` rather than on the object you allocated.

Release `self` before you return `nil` and all should be good.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case there was obviously an error that needed to be fixed, but I have seen at times a need to suppress warnings that are completely understood to be non problems (i.e. a leak reported that is not actually a leak).

This is what I expected to need to do here, but it turned out that there was an actual leak.  So I am glad it got fixed.  I immediately found another problem that was a clear an unmistakable "false positive" (I know that the error is reported as a "potential leak" so in reality it isn't a false positive, but it doesn't mean I want to see it in the report every time I run the analyzer).

Because of this I still had the question of how to suppress these warnings.  It turns out you can easily wrap code that you want the analyzer to bypass in a ifdef check for __clang_analyzer.

```
#ifndef __clang_analyzer__
  ... code you want to ignore ...
#endif
```

There was a very good write up on this [here](http://xcodebook.com/2011/08/handling-false-positives-with-the-static-analyzer/).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `[self release]` before `self = nil`.

The object you get from `alloc` has a reference count of +1 which needs to be balanced by a call to `release` or `autorelease`. For the case where you return your actual object from `sha1HashWithHashBytes:length:` the `autorelease` in that class method takes care of everything.

For the case you return `nil` your `init` method is the last one that has a reference to that allocated object so it has to release it.