# How can I convince XCode's Analyzer that this isn't a leak?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-analysis

The static analyzer is informing me that the following code has a potential leak.  I don't understand how there's any room for a leak.  Further, I don't understand how the analyzer can be so helpful across the entire project yet miss something this easy.

My assumption is that the analyzer is right and I am leaking.  But how?

```
+ (McFieldDefinition *) freeformFieldDefinition {
    return [[[McFieldDefinition alloc] initWithText:@"0201FFM100"] autorelease];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual message it is giving you? The code you have here looks fine, but it may be telling you the allow or init methods have a leaks and it is materialized here. Many time you can expand the leak information and it will trace paths and give more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting this question.  I finally found an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668026/300986.

The problem was in my init method:

```
- (id) initWithText:(NSString *)text {
    if (!text) return nil;
    if ([text length] < 7) return nil;
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        // do stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

Those two guard clauses return nil if I don't like the text variable.  self is already alloc'ed by that point, so it's Analyzer 1, bmauter 0.

Here's my new version:

```
- (id) initWithText:(NSString *)text {
    self = [self init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    if (!text || [text length] < 7) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }

    // do stuff

    return self;
}
```